QGIS, GRASS - Voronoi skeleton at cycles
I have some vector-geometries (made from rasters earlier) in QGIS and try to find the center line within them with v.voronoi.skeleton, so far so good:

However, if the geometries get more complicated, voronoi chooses a side for its triangles...

Is there a smart solution of how to cleverly split the geometries or tell QGIS / GRASS to calculate this for both paths? Data can be found here.

I solved it with a work around using multiple other steps from different  processing toolboxes in QGIS, namely GDAL and WhiteBoxTools (WBT). My custom model3 in QGIS does the following steps:
r.null -> GDAL Polygonize -> WBT SmoothVectors -> WBT Fix geometries -> QGIS Delete holes
After that install the HCMGIS plugin and run skeletonize. For my data is does a nice job withou leaving to much post-processing to do...
